Ubuntu 10 Migration from VMWare to HV
We're using our backup solution to migrate an instance of Ubuntu Server 10.04 from VMWare to HV. The migration was successful after adding the HV modules. The problem we are running in to is that Ubuntu boots completely to the login screen, the network pings about 8 times, and then just stops. If I change the NIC to DHCP, it will get an address on initial boot but has the same issue where it will stop pinging. IFDOWN and then IFUP does not fix the issue. Only rebooting the system will get it to ping again, but only for about 10 seconds. Any ideas on what might be causing this, or where to start looking?

Ubuntu 10.04 has reached the end of life. It is not supported and off topic here.

Only supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site. Whilst your OS/release is unstated, your question text clearly implies an unsupported and thus off-topic release of Ubuntu. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic
